# Reading an MCP23S17 I/O expander port with the Arduino SPI library

Tags: sketch, spi

I am trying to read an MCP23S17 I/O expander port B with the Arduino SPI library.
The following example is simple as possible, and I still can not get it to work.
[image]
The setup is an MCP23S17 I/O expander on a Teensy LC controller.
MCP23S17 port B pins are alternately grounded and energized.
I confirmed the pin voltages with a multi-meter.
Variable portBState is a bitwise reading of port B, and printed.

Expected output is:

```
10101010
```

Actual output is:

```
11111111
```

Sketch:

```
#include <SPI.h>

const uint8_t ADDR = 0x20;      //MCP23S17 address, all 3 ADDR pins are grounded
const uint8_t OPCODE_READ  = (ADDR << 1 | 0x01); //MCP23S17 read command

const uint8_t IODIRB = 0x01;
const uint8_t GPIOB  = 0x13;

uint8_t portBState = 0;                 //bit wise

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(1000);

    pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);                //configure controller's Slave Select pin to output
    digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);             //disable Slave Select
    SPI.begin();

    //IODIRB register is already configured to input by default

    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings (SPI_CLOCK_DIV8, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
    digitalWrite(SS, LOW);              //enable Slave Select
      SPI.transfer(OPCODE_READ);        //read command
      SPI.transfer(GPIOB);              //register address to read data from
      portBState = SPI.transfer(0);     //save the data (0 is dummy data to send)
    digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);             //disable Slave Select
    SPI.endTransaction();               //release the SPI bus

    Serial.println(portBState, BIN);    //should print 10101010
}

void loop() { }
```

Why is the output not "10101010"?

The controller is Teensy LC (3.3 volts) on Arduino 1.6.7.
SPI library: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI
More links in the comments below (I don't have enough reputation points to post more links in the question).

Comment: Teensy LC pin out: https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/card6a_rev2.png

Comment: MCP23S17 datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001952C.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now.  Here is what was missing:
A yellow jumper from the micro-controller MOSI pin to the MCP23S17 SO pin.
So the read command can travel from micro-controller to MCP23S17.

[image]